# Disable pop-up compilation buffer in AucTex

Tags: auctex

How can I set AucTex to either (a) not pop up that annoying compilation buffer every time I `C-c C-c` or (b) only pop it up if compilation is not successful? (b) is preferable, but if it's too hard then I'm fine with (a).

Comment: (a) is not the default behavior, no compilation buffer is shown by default. You activated it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this in my latex config, but I forget where it come from ...it does (b)

```
(defadvice TeX-LaTeX-sentinel
    (around mg-TeX-LaTeX-sentinel-open-output activate)
  "Open output when there are errors."
  ;; Run `TeX-LaTeX-sentinel' as usual.
  ad-do-it
  ;; Check for the presence of errors.
  (when
      (with-current-buffer TeX-command-buffer
        (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern (TeX-master-file))))
    ;; If there are errors, open the output buffer.
    (TeX-recenter-output-buffer nil)))
```

Comment: I guess it's my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185763  But really, compilation buffer is not shown by default, my guess is that the OP activated it with `(setq TeX-show-compilation t)`.

Comment: @giordano Actually, I eventually figured out it was because I was using emac's latex-mode (I think). Anyway, I don't have the problem now.

Answer (score 1):

When I was looking for to avoid this, I didn't found. But I finnaly found a solution to get around the problem by using `latexmk`. The following code may help you :

```
(defun run-latexmk ()
  "It compiles the current document"
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
         (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %t" 'TeX-master-file)
         master-file)
    (minibuffer-message "latexmk done")))
```

This was inspired by [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115247/how-to-make-latexmk-run-the-appropriate-amount-of-times) about how to make `latexmk` run the appropriate amount of times.

Then you can rebind `C-c C-c` with something like `(local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") #'run-latexmk)`.